# how to solve the instagram api tag limit?

Tags: instagram

I want to use instagram api like Tinder app. (but Tinder uses one specific person's account, but I want to use tags.) 
so, if I call #travel, then it showes 30 of #travel hashtag pics.

But there is API call limit 5000/hour, 
do you know how Tinder use instagram api call ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

5000/hr is per `access_token`, so if you make the user connect using Instagram in your app, then each user will have 5000/hr.

If you dont want to make your users connect with Instagram, then you have to cache the results on server using your `access_token` and then serve results from your server